# VBA in Excel to select a cell on other tab

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to update multi PivotTables by changing the date on another sheet.  I can do this if I use a range on the same sheet by using

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = _
    "11/1/2010"
```

and change it to

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = _
    Range("C1").Text
```

but I can not get the right string  to add to the range for `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Text`

Answer (score 1):

Just DIM's the location and called it from there.  It worked so I'm happy.
Thanks for looking